# Improving performance of website which has many animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

i made a website to play music, it uses a lot of animations when you press notes or playback a song. I'm having issues with performance, especially on mobile so i wanted to figure out what was causing it. I went through profiling using google chrome and it's telling me there is a lot of `Recalculate Style` happening, and that 30ish elements are affected each time. I've tried making the animations as performant as i could, i use transform scale and background-color animations, plus i added the `will-change` prop to the element that has the most changes, in hope to solve issues, but i haven't been able to gain much.

I was thinking that maybe the biggest issue might be with animating background-color as that will cause a repaint throughout the animation, but i still dont understand why it would cause a `Recalculate Style`?
[Here is the link for the beta of the website](https://music-apps.pages.dev/genshinMusic/#/). If anyone could help me track down the issue.

PS: to try and stress test the app, [Download and import this song here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/771432833034092554/985872769650679808/Through_the_Fire_and_Flames.genshinsheet_9.json)

Here is some graphs:

[image: chrome profiler]
[image: bottom up]
[image: event log]

Comment: Have you tried `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` on a containing div that animates.  Even if not doing 3d, this can help browsers as it tells them to use hardware acceleration.  It's not used by default as it's not very good for vertically scrolling content, but seen as your animating a section it will likely be useful here.

Comment: @Keith yes I had it before, I removed it in favour of `will-change` today, performance is a bit better with since last version, but it might not be only because of `will-change`

Comment: did you consider memoized components?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava they are all memoized, if you run the react profiler you will see that only the notes that animate are re rendered

Comment: Looking at your HTML, your buttons are SVG's, your then changing the background colour, because these are transparent SVG's, I've a gut feeling this is a performance hit.   What might help is having the different states of the buttons all rendered, and then just change the visibility, this will hopefully then prevent constant composition of the transparency happing..

Comment: Another option, is convert each state into a PNG.  If you think what's happening here each time you change the button class, it's having to redraw the entire SVG each time, having the states already rendered into a PNG should give you way more performance.

Comment: @Keith issue is that i have custom themes for the app so the user can change the background and colors of everything, so that would be complicated to do. to test i disabled the transition for the background color and that cut down the "rendering" part to 600ms, from 3000 of the old one, so yes i think the issue comes to drawing the svg on top of the background animating. Now i just have to figure out how to improve the performance of that, if possible

Comment: You can render the SVG to a PNG at runtime, so themes shouldn't be an issue.  Seen as your using React it wouldn't be too difficult to make that into a component that does all this for you.  I'm assuming you currently have a component already that has some state to say what it's rendered like, so also shouldn't be too much change of existing code, it could be a simple drop in replacement.

Comment: @Keith To convert at runtime u mean to use canvas to render the svg and change the color, then convert the canvas to a blob and use it in the image, right? If that's the case then ye its doable, since i'd have to only cache the note itself, the background is animated and handled by the browser. 

For now i made it so the background animation is removed when you are in song playback, that improves performance by more than double.

About SVGs and PNGs, svgs are harder to render because they need to be redrawn everytime they change, while pngs are just "rendered" directly, right?

Comment: Your also rendering the foreground of the notes, so I would expect you need a PNG for each state here.   eg.  your doing `fill: #f2ecec!important; stroke: #f2ecec!important;`

Comment: @Keith if you want you can create an answer to the post specifying the fix and what is causing it so that other people who might have this issue can get a help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the website, and the discussions in comments.   It looks like most your performance issue is due to SVG compositing each time the note changes.  SVG rendering in browsers these days is pretty fast, but still not as fast as say a PNG render.

Two options came to mind,.

1. Create all the notes with the styles set, and then set the visibility.  Only issue here is, I'm not sure if the browser will still do a re-render of the SVG when it comes in / out of visibility.  Maybe a very Low Opacity could also help here instead.  Basically have all the notes states with position absolute on top of each other, the active state would have full opacity, the others a very low one.
2. Dynamically create the SVG's into PNG's for each state, you could then just flip the PNG's, which should be way faster than the SVG doing a re-draw each time.

Personally I like option 1., but will just need to do some tests.  Doing Opacity transitions is certainly fast & smooth in the browser, so you would expect the SVG shouldn't require re-render.  I say very low opacity, just in case the browser sees an opacity as 0, as been equivalent to visibility hidden, and decided to loose the render canvas and do another SVG draw when it becomes visible again.   Again, some testing here would confirm.